# Windows docker default encoding

Tags: docker, encoding

we faced a problem with default encoding in Windows Docker, is there anyone familiar with this? Here is our scenario.
Running docker engine **19.03.8** on `Windows 10 Enterprise 1903` with our homemade image based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` result in the following encoding in docker instance:

```
PS C:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
```

However, running the same docker image on `AWS Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 1809` result in the following default encoding

```
17:38:11  C:\>powershell -Command "[System.Text.Encoding]::Default" 
17:38:28  
17:38:28  
17:38:28  IsSingleByte      : True
17:38:28  BodyName          : iso-8859-1
17:38:28  EncodingName      : Western European (Windows)
17:38:28  HeaderName        : Windows-1252
17:38:28  WebName           : Windows-1252
17:38:28  WindowsCodePage   : 1252
17:38:28  IsBrowserDisplay  : True
17:38:28  IsBrowserSave     : True
17:38:28  IsMailNewsDisplay : True
17:38:28  IsMailNewsSave    : True
17:38:28  EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
17:38:28  DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
17:38:28  IsReadOnly        : True
17:38:28  CodePage          : 1252
```

Does anyone know what was happening behind the scene?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem, have you made any progress?

Comment: @Cliveburr Sorry I don't have any clues yet. I checked the default encoding on the host as well and they are identical. I assume this might because of the Windows Server and Windows 10 differences?

Comment: I solved my problem with this option "docker run --isolation = process" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container

Comment: @Cliveburr Appreciated!